# Integrating over $\theta$ for a rotating ring in the Ehrenfest paradox

Tags: special-relativity

Assume that we have a rotating ring in plane $xy$. If $\theta$ is an arbitrary angle in the said plane which its vertex is at the center of rotation (center of the ring), what would be the upper bound for the integration of a given function $f(\theta)$ over a complete revolution? (Do the calculation from the viewpoint of the observer located outside the ring and at rest relative to its center)

If the plate does not rotate, the upper bound is evidently $2\pi$ providing the lower bound is $0$. However, for a rotating ring, according to SRT, the circumference of the ring is Lorentz contracted, and it is rational to use $2\alpha \pi$ instead of $2\pi$ for the upper bound, where $\alpha=\sqrt{1-r^2\omega^2/c^2}$, and $r$ is the radius of the ring. Aren't I correct?

Recall that one may claim that the Lorentz contraction does not apply to the angle, but rather the length of the circumference, and thus we shall use $2\pi$ for a rotating ring as well.

Answer (score 0):

The angle does not change, but the lenght of the line elements does ($dL_0$ is the line element when the disc is at rest):

$$dL=dL_0/\gamma=rd\theta/\gamma$$

then:

$$d\theta=\frac{\gamma dL}{r}$$

So you integrate $d\theta$ between $0$ and $2\pi$, and $dL$ between $0$ and $L_0/\gamma$.